# File upload exceeds the defined ini size in Zend 1

Tags: forms, zend-framework, php-7.2

I am trying to implement multiple file upload in my form. I am using PHP 7.2 and Zend Framework version 1. Problem is whenever I submit my form, file input "attachments" complains with message: "File 'attachments' exceeds the defined ini size".

```
$this->setEnctype(\Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART); //rendered as <form id="bug_report_form" name="bug_report_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/feedback/bug-report" method="post">
```

Now I have checked my ini settings:

**max_file_uploads** - 20

**post_max_size** - 50M

**upload_max_filesize** - also 50M

All I am uploading is some few KB jpeg files. I also added enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form element. I have also checked and made sure that php fileinfo extension is enabled.

Here is how file element looks in Zend Form:

```
$attachments = new \Zend_Form_Element_File('attachments');
$attachments->setLabel('Screenshots');
$attachments->setAttrib('multiple', true);
$attachments->setAttrib('isArray', true);
```

Even after removing multiple and isArray attributes and uploading only one small file, I would still get same error.

EDIT: I just realised that my form does not reload page upon submitting and $_FILES array is completely empty, could this be, because form posts as AJAX?

Comment: Did you get those values from ini files, or from `phpinfo()`? Because it is possible you have multiple ini configurations (like, one for apache and one for cli). What's the result of `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: @Ermenegildo I got these values, calling phpinfo() from inside Zend Controller.